# A Class to be accessed by another class only

Tags: c++

I have a class which declares some static variables:

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
private:
static int x;
public:
static int y;
static getX(){ return A::x;}
static setX(int z){ A::x = z;}
};

int A::x = 0;
int A::y = 0;
```

Now class A can be accessed by anyone/anywhere and its member variables can be manipulate. How can I allow only one another class that will have access to class A static variables / methods?

```
class B
{
public:
void showX(){A::setX(9) ; std::cout << A::getX() << std::endl;}
void showY(){A::y = 8; std::cout << A::y << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
B b1;
b1.showX();
b1.showY();
}
```

Comment: Read up on `private` and  `friend`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define `A` inside `B` as private class.

```
#include <iostream>

class B
{
    class A
    {
    private:
        static int x;
    public:
        static int y;
        static int getX() {
            return A::x;
        }
        static void setX(int z) {
            A::x = z;
        }
    };

public:
    void showX() {
        A::setX(9) ;
        std::cout << A::getX() << std::endl;
    }
    void showY() {
        A::y = 8;
        std::cout << A::y << std::endl;
    }
};

int B::A::x = 0;
int B::A::y = 0;

int main()
{
    B b1;
    b1.showX();
    b1.showY();
}
```

Comment: Would the destructor of B will also call destructor of A - which is what currently I do not wish to happen?

Comment: There is no instance of A constructed - so no destructor will be called anywhere

Comment: Thanks - one clarification - so when B destructor is called - class A static variable will still exists in memory and not be destroyed - in other words they would be destroyed only when program terminates?

Comment: Yes static variables are initialized before main starts and destructed after main finished

Answer (score 3):

If the class should *only* be known in one other class, then I would say it should be a private implementation detail of that class

```
class B
{
private:
    class A
    {
    private:
        static int x;
    public:
        static int y;
        static int getX(){ return A::x;}
        static void setX(int z){ A::x = z;}
    };

public:
    void showX(){A::setX(9) ; std::cout << A::getX() << std::endl;}
    void showY(){A::y = 8; std::cout << A::y << std::endl;}
};

int B::A::x = 0;
int B::A::y = 0;

int main()
{
    B b1;
    b1.showX();
    b1.showY();
}
```

Now the existence of `A` isn't known by anyone except `B`.

Comment: Would the destructor of B will also call destructor of A - which is what currently I do not wish to happen?

Comment: No it would not, because `B` does not have an `A` member, it is merely the scope that the definition lies in.

Comment: Thanks - one clarification - so when B destructor is called - class A static variable will still exists in memory and not be destroyed - in other words they would be destroyed only when program terminates?

Answer (score 2):

CRTP lets you do this without touching B:

```
class B;

template<class A>
class A_shared_with_B {
private:
  static int y;
  static int getX(){ return A::x;}
  static void setX(int z){ A::x = z;}
  friend class B;
};

class A:public A_shared_with_B<A> {
  friend class A_shared_with_B<A>;
private:
  static int x;
};
```

now `B` has access to the `private` contents of `A_shared_with_B`, `A_shared_with_B` has access to the `private` contents of `A`, and `B` does not have direct access to the `private` contents of `A`.

If you are willing to modify `B` and rename `A`, naming `A` within the `private` section of `B` makes the name difficult to reach from outside `B`, which is similar to the above access control.  A nice advantage to this technique is that you can grant proxy access to `A` by passing an otherwise useless instance of `A` to an external `template` function:

```
template<class A>
void has_proxy_A_access( A ) {
  std::cout << A::getX();
}
```

where instances of `B` can call `has_proxy_A_access( A{} )` and grant rights to use `A` to a given (template) function.

Answer (score 0):

There are already answer showing how to make `A` an inner class. For the sake of completeness here is the `private`+`friend` solution (already proposed in a comment by Neil Butterworth):

```
#include <iostream>
class A {
private:
    friend class B;
    static int x;  
    static int y;
    static getX(){ return A::x;}
    static setX(int z){ A::x = z;}
};
```

A `friend` has access to all members of a class, so you can make all members of `A` private and grant only `B` access to them by making it a friend.